How do I prove this statement on this article?
So, a friend of mine showed me this article "A Geometric Perspective on Quantum Parameter Estimation" (link in the end of the question), and there is a statement on page 5 (equation 23) that I cannot figure out how to prove.
$$-E_{x|\theta}[\theta\frac{\partial \ln p(x|\theta)}{\partial\theta}] = 1$$
For context, this part of the article is introducing parameter estimation, and this section later introduces Fisher Information and the Cramér-Rao bound.
Also, the article states that the equation above could be proved using partial integration.
Link of the article for reference: https://pure.strath.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/105153996/Sidhu_Kok_AVS_QS_2020_Geometric_perspective_on_quantum_parameter_estimation.pdf
Edit1: I have tried the following solution, but it leads to the result being $0$ instead of $1$, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:
$$-\int p(x|\theta)\theta\frac{1}{p(x|\theta)}\frac{\partial p(x|\theta)}{\partial \theta} dx$$
$$= -\int \theta \frac{\partial p(x|\theta)}{\partial \theta} dx$$
$$= -\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\int p(x|\theta)  dx$$
$$= -\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}1 = 0$$

Your calculation looks correct to me, I think it's the article that's wrong. If I'm reading it correctly, equation (21) doesn't hold for $g = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log p(x|\theta)$. Instead it should read
$$
E_{x|\theta}\left[\hat\theta(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log p(x|\theta)\right] = \int \hat\theta(x)\frac{\partial p(x|\theta)}{\partial\theta} dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\int\hat\theta(x)p(x|\theta)dx = 1
$$
(the last equality following since $\hat\theta$ is unbiased). This leads to $T=1$, but not for the reasons given in the article.
Edit: I'll just note that there additional differences in the arxiv version of this article (additional minus signs, expectations over $x,\theta$ rather than $x|\theta$). Also in the version you linked to, it's unclear to me what $E_{\theta|x}$ in equation (21) is supposed to mean, since they earlier state they are adopting a frequentist (rather than Bayesian) approach. So I think the article is just sloppy here.

Thank you so much for your answer! It makes a lot of sense.
